# Mystery LEGO bags

Tags: set-identification

I bought 3 sealed bags of LEGO at the second hand store. They are unopened but have no box/ instructions.
I looked at some other threads here and tried to identify the sets using piece numbers and the Peeron site but haven't had luck. 
I'm hoping to post pictures here and hopefully someone can help me.....
The first bag has a police theme, a robber and a bubble canopy window. I believe it's the complete set as the bag has no number.
The other two are harder, they are numbered bags so obviously part of larger sets (both 6 so not part of the same set.....)

[image]
[image]

Comment: you should probably open a new question for the first photo

Comment: The first one is 60004-1 fire station I'm pretty sure, at least part of it. You should add another question for it though

Answer (score 9):

Found it, it's LEGO City Brickmaster, a book-set (ISBN-13: 978-1405356237),

[image]

How did I do it ?
I used my trusted [pyrebrickable](https://github.com/rienafairefr/pyrebrickable/blob/master/examples/search_set2.py), using a few pieces in the bottom right corner, and the only set that contains both black knit cap, white cap, and light bluish gray 1x1 cone is this one, numbered DKCity-1 in the rebrickable dataset.

Good building !

Comment: Nice! I didn't get beyond 60049 with bricklink. I would delete the old part of your answer.

Comment: You're right, I removed the deprecated part :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! Any idea how to get instructions for this (since they are  within a book) any ideas  about the other bag? (it's only part of a larger set).

Comment: Also, How can I leave good reviews/rating for my helpers?

Comment: Building shouldn't be really hard based on what we see on the image, I think.

Comment: That source you were using is broken, it leads to a 404 page.

Comment: Thanks @mindstormsboi, fixed the link

Answer (score 1):

First picture has parts from [Fire Station (60004)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60004-1) set. Identified by unique combination of [Garage Roller Door Section without Handle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4218&idColor=15#T=C&C=15) in Trans-Light Blue and [Brick, Modified 1 x 2 with Open O Clip Thick (Vertical Grip)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30237b&idColor=3#T=C&C=3) in Yellow.

[image]

The other set has been correctly identified by rienafairefr.